# ajax preflight fails with OPTIONS response 200 in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, preflight

I have the following code:

```
Util.xmlGet = function(uriend, callback) {
    var xmlhttp;
    var uri;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for modern browsers
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {// code for dinosaurs
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(document.URL.startsWith("file://")) {
        uri = "https://tomcat.realm:8443/worldmodel/worldmodel?";
    } else {
        uri = "/worldmodel/worldmodel?"
    }
    alert(uri+uriend);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        alert("readystate="+xmlhttp.readyState+", status="+xmlhttp.status);
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==0) {
            alert("preflight OK");
        }
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            alert("calling back");
            callback(xmlhttp.responseXML);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET",uri+uriend,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send();     
   };
```

I see the following alerts when calling it:

- the URI
- readystate=1, status=0
- readystate=2, status=0
- readystate=4, status=0
- preflight OK

An OPTIONS request is sent by the browser, and received a "200" response. More exactly:

```
https://tomcat.realm:8443/worldmodel/worldmodel?type=thing
Request Method:
OPTIONS
Status Code:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Request Headers
14:35:30.000
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Origin:nullHost:tomcat.realm:8443
Connection:keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Accept-Language:hu,en-us;q=0.8,es;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflateAccept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8


Response Headers  Δ5ms
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date:Thu, 06 Jun 2013 12:35:30 GMT
Content-Length:0
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, TRACE, OPTIONS
```

The GET request is never sent, no more states from the onreadystatechange.

This was done from a Firefox 21.0 Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical - 1.0 (this is what help/about firefox reports), on a html file in the local filesystem.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Doesn't firefox prevent xhr request from files that are on your local filesystem to anywhere? First becuse it can't reference the same domain (local file system) for security reasons. Second because it cannot access other domains because of the same origin policy. What happens when you install the forcecors plugin and activate it with view => toolbars => addon bar. Then click on the "cors" text in the right bottom corner. Now you can make xhr requests from anywhere to anywhere. For more info you can check wikipedia on same origin policy.

Comment: Tried it, thanks for the hint. The headers added by cors is shown in the OPTIONS response as the Web Console sees it, but all other symptoms are the same.

Comment: I could open up an xhr connection with the forecors plugin active from a local file. Opened a file with jquery (all local) and pasted the following code in the console: `$.ajax("http://www.google.com.hk");` The request finished and I could see the response in the console. When forcecors is not active the request turns red and I don't see the response. If your web server sends the correct cors response headers it should work without forcecors.

Comment: Tried with dojo:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5742410/

Answer (score 0):

> Doesn't firefox prevent xhr request from files that are on your local filesystem to anywhere? First becuse it can't reference the same domain (local file system) for security reasons. Second because it cannot access other domains because of the same origin policy.